# How to suppress warnings for file included from header

Tags: qt, gcc, qmake, suppress-warnings

I use GCC `-Weffc++` option in my Qt project. To suppress warnings from Qt headers i add  `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem $(QTDIR)\include`.
But this doesn't suppress all warnings, i still get annoying warnings from **QUuid** class because `$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore\quuid.h`
file includes
`..\..\src\corelib\plugin\quuid.h`.
I tried to add
`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem $(QTDIR)\src`
and
`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem $(QTDIR)\src\corelib\plugin`
but it didn't help. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I don't get any warnings from `Qt` files with `g++`, assuming you mean `g++`?

Comment: Yes, i mean `g++`. Maybe it depends on Qt version or platform?

Comment: Post your `Qt` version and platform.  Also, did you build `Qt` yourself, or did it come pre-made (a Windows download, or from your package manager)?

Comment: It is Qt 4.6.2 for x32 Windows from official Qt SDK for Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to suppress each directory separately. Example from my project:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem "$$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/qt5" -isystem "$$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/qt5/QtWidgets" \
                  -isystem "$$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/QtXml" -isystem "/usr/include/qt5/QtGui" \
                  -isystem "$$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/QtCore"
```

Or, to automate the above for the exact Qt modules you have enabled:

```
for (inc, QT) {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem \"$$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/Qt$$system("echo $$inc | sed 's/.*/\u&/'")\"
}

# Still need this separately:
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem "$$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/qt5"
```

Comment: And from a non QT project?

Comment: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS it is equivalent for CXXFLAGS in makefile.

Comment: Tried the automated method: `'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 2):

This thread helped me a lot, thank you @dismine, but it didn't work for me in some cases, so I'm pasting my solution ( I don't want to edit the first answer )

I have enhanced it to get rid of the `sed` command, so it is cross-platform, it uses standard qmake's replace functions `$$split()`, `$$join()`, `$$upper()`, and `$$take_first()`.

The `moduleList` local variable is needed, it doesn't work without it.

Following works with `Qt >=5.15.2` (it of course can work on lower versions, but I didn't test it):

```
# Mark all Qt headers as system headers

!win32-clang-msvc:!mingw:!unix: \
    return()

win32-clang-msvc: \
    optionToken = -imsvc
else: \
    optionToken = -isystem

# Avoid following error on MSYS2 with Qt5:
# fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
# Everywhere else it is needed to avoid warnings from system headers
!if(mingw:versionAtMost(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5)): \
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$optionToken $$shell_quote($$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS])

for(module, QT) {
    equals(module, "testlib"): \
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += \
            $$optionToken $$shell_quote($$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/QtTest)
    else {
        # Capitalize a first letter, result: -isystem <path>/include/QtCore
        moduleList = $$split(module, )
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += \
            $$optionToken $$shell_quote($$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/Qt$$upper(\
                          $$take_first(moduleList))$$join(moduleList, ))
    }
}

unset(optionToken)
unset(moduleList)
```

It dynamically generates correct `-isystem` or `-imsvc` compiler flags on the base of currently used Qt modules, so you can include this code in different projects/sub-projects.

I can recommend creating the `system_headers.prf` and enabling it using the qmake CONFIG option `CONFIG += system_headers`.

The original [tiny_system_headers.prf](https://github.com/silverqx/TinyORM/blob/main/qmake/features/tiny_system_headers.prf) source code is from the [TinyORM](https://www.tinyorm.org) project.