# How to include Qt's headers with -isystem (system headers) with qmake and qt5?

Tags: qt, g++, warnings, qt5, qmake

I compile my Qt5-based project with warnings enabled on g++:

```
# project.pro file
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Weffc++
```

When compiling, Qt produces lots of warnings (1000+ with just one simple widget), hiding the warnings from my code.

How to tell qmake to use the `-isystem` switch when specifying the Qt's headers rather than `-I` to suppress the warnings? I don't want to turn warnings off I want to keep them for my code.

NOTE: I checked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4199505/143504) but it does not work in my case, it might be only for Qt4, I use Qt5.

<s>NOTE 2: this is an [acknowledged bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-7220), I am looking for a workaround.</s> I use a recent version of qmake compiled from sources 5.4.1, this version passes system headers from `/include` and `/usr/include` as system headers but not the Qt's headers.

NOTE 3: I know CMake would work but this is not an option for me.

Comment: The "workaround" is to submit a patch to qmake that adds support for this. Or to switch to cmake, where I hope this is a solved problem.

Comment: I have a recent version of qmake (I will edit the question to mention this). I tried with CMake: `include_directories(SYSTEM dir1 dir2)` this works but I need to stick with qmake. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found two ways to suppress warnings from Qt's headers, one way by installing Qt in system's path (as suggested in the other answer) and the other directly from your `pro` file by using GCC flags.

1. When building your own Qt, configure the header's installation path to one of your system path:

   ```
   $ ./configure -headerdir /usr/local/include
   ```

   System paths are `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include` or one of the rest listed in:

   ```
   $ grep DEFAULT_INCDIRS mkspecs/qconfig.pri
   QMAKE_DEFAULT_INCDIRS = /usr/include/c++/4.8 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8 /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include /usr/local/include /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/include
   ```

   Source: [this thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.devel/17040) in Qt's devel list.
2. Or directly in your Qt `pro` file, simply add the `-isystem` flag into the `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`:

   ```
   # the line below suppresses warnings generated by Qt's header files: we tell
   # GCC to treat Qt's headers as "system headers" with the -isystem flag
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]
   ```

   The resulting GCC command line looks like:

   ```
   g++ -c -pipe -isystem /usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/include -Wall ...
       -I/usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/include
       -I/usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/include/QtWidgets
       ...
   ```

   Note how the Qt's include paths are still added with `-I`, allowing Qt Creator to "see" all Qt headers, but GCC sees the `-isystem` flag and suppresses warnings for all subfolders.

Comment: No need of that `$$system` -- just use `$$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]` :)

Comment: I didn't know about the brackets syntax--I tried with just `$$QT_INSTALL_HEADERS` and it did not work, I was missing the brackets! I will update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Method 2: If you have several folders inside Qt, you should then add `-isystem $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/...` for every folder: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20264397

Comment: This works only for gcc-like compilers.  Visual Studio's equivalent switch is `/external:I <path>`.  https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17904

Answer (score 2):

Did you install Qt in a **system** path? Otherwise qmake won't pass `-isystem`.

You can check which paths are system paths according to qmake by reading your `mkspec/qconfig.pri` (after you run `configure`), the system paths are set to the `QMAKE_DEFAULT_INCDIRS` variable. Here:

```
QMAKE_DEFAULT_INCDIRS = /usr/include/c++/4.8 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8 /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include /usr/local/include /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/include
```